# Shyness and introvert

Tags: sunnah

So I am very shy to talk to people and I don't even talk  to my relatives that much as well and in school I feel weird to talk to others or opposite gender
I only talk to friends openly and I don't want to meet people
Even if I meet them I can't talk properly and the whole thing becomes akward

What does islam say about it
Is it a promblem and what should I do about it ..